# Simple .html filter in python - modify text elements only

Tags: python, html, filter

I need to filter a rather long (but very regular) set of .html files to modify a few constructs *only* if they appear in text elements.

One good example is to change `<p><div class="speech">it's hard to find his "good" side! He has <i>none</i>!<div></p>` to `<p><div class="speech">it's hard to find his &ldquo;good&rdquo; side! He has <i>none</i>!<div></p>`.

I can easily parse my files with `html.parser`, but it's unclear how to generate result file, which should be as similar to input as possible (no reformatting).

I had a look to beautiful-soup, but it really seems too big for this (supposedly?) simple task.

Note: I do *not* need/want to serve .html files to a browser of any kind; I just need them updated (possibli in-place) with (slightly) changed content.

UPDATE:

Following @soundstripe advice Iwrote the following code:

```
import bs4
from re import sub

def handle_html(html):
    sp = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
    for e in list(sp.strings):
        s = sub(r'"([^"]+)"', r'&ldquo;\1&rdquo;', e)
        if s != e:
            e.replace_with(s)
    return str(sp).encode()

raw = b"""<p><div class="speech">it's hard to "find" his "good" side! He has <i>none</i>!<div></p>"""
new = handle_html(raw)
print(raw)
print(new)
```

Unfortunately BeautifulSoup tries to be too smart from its (and my) own good:

```
b'<p><div class="speech">it\'s hard to "find" his "good" side! He has <i>none</i>!<div></p>'
b'<p><div class="speech">it\'s hard to &amp;ldquo;find&amp;rdquo; his &amp;ldquo;good&amp;rdquo; side! He has <i>none</i>!<div></div></div></p>'
```

i.e.: it transforms plain `&` to `&amp;` thus breaking `&ldquo;` entity (notice I'm working with bytearrays, not strings. Is it relevant?).

How can I fix this?

Comment: you can use selenium webdriver for that

Comment: @Code_Ninja: at first glance it looks even more use-cannon-to-swat-a-fly than beautiful-soup. Did I miss something?

Comment: haha, dont be scared of the API, selenium webdriver gives you more features than beautiful-soup, as it's main aim of creation is to track and automate changes on a website at front end level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you wouldn't use BeautifulSoup. Here's an example that replaces your quotes like you're asking.

```
import re
import bs4

raw = b"""<p><div class="speech">it's hard to find his "good" side! He has <i>none</i>!<div></p> to <p><div class="speech">it's hard to find his &ldquo;good&rdquo; side! He has <i>none</i>!<div></p>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(raw, features='html.parser')

def replace_quotes(s):
    return re.sub(r'"([^"]+)"', r'&ldquo;\1&rdquo;', e)


for e in list(soup.strings):
    # wrapping the new string in BeautifulSoup() call to correctly parse entities
    new_string = bs4.BeautifulSoup(replace_quotes(e))
    e.replace_with(new_string)

# use the soup.encode() formatter keyword to specify you want html entities in your output
new = soup.encode(formatter='html')


print(raw)
print(new)
```

Comment: Please see updated Question; we are almost there... but not quite.

Comment: Normally you'd need to open another post (and do a little research first) to ask a different question but I'm feeling nice today :P

Comment: I'll point out this re.sub() pattern will only work on matched pairs of quotes in a single HTML string. You probably want something more like what Word does for smart quotes-- if the quote is followed by a letter, it should be a left quote. If it is followed by a space or punctuation, it should be a right quote.

Comment: Cure is worse than illness. Using `bs4.BeautifulSoup(replace_quotes(e))` wraps string in `<html><body><p>...</p></body></html>`; the outer `<html><body>...</body></html>` are removed by replace_with, but `<p>...</p>` remains and breaks havoc with formatting. I will accept Your answer because i made it work simply changing `&ldquo;` with `“` as I don't really care for html entities in final product. Thanks.

Comment: I am aware of limitations of `re.sub(...)`, but I still think this is the best option; one of my actual snippets reads: `<br/>« <span class="speech">Ho visto io quello che è successo. La ruota è passata su un pietrone che la ha spostata di un palmo. Un palmo più in là c’era il vuoto. Non ho fatto a tempo nemmeno a dirti "attento!"</span> »<br/>« <span class="speech">Andiamo a vedere?</span> »<br/>` it's not very obvious what to do with the "closing" quotes as it's surrounded by punctuation (and this is only the very first hit). Any insight welcome.